# Leaflet Map Clustering zoom in not working on close points

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, jquery

The Cluster don't get zoom in, it just split like this if the points are close to each other , in other clusters if the points are not closer they just get zoom and working fine, I want to disable this affect if possible and make it zoom on clicking on it.Kindly guide me if this is possible or not.

Points :

LAT 31.4926473    LON 74.3759229
LAT 31.4923959    LON 74.375927

[image]

```
   function setMap(cat_ids) {    

    $.ajax({
        url: '{!!route('all-outlets-map-client-portal')!!}',
        data: {
            cat_ids: cat_ids, project_filter_applied:project_filter_applied, geofilters:geofilters
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            locations = data;
            ids       = data.project_ids;
            // console.log(ids); 
             initialise = 1;                           
            populate(cat_ids);          
        }
    });

    function populate(cat_ids) {

        $.each(cat_ids, function( index, value ){                 
            cities = '';              
            layers_variables[value]           = L.layerGroup();
            layers_variables_clusters[value]  = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

            map.addLayer(layers_variables_clusters[value]);  
            var color = getRandomColor();
            for (var i = 0; i < locations[value].length; i++) {               
                var id  = locations[value][i].id;
                var lat = locations[value][i].latitude;
                var lng = locations[value][i].longitude;

                var marker = new L.circleMarker(new L.LatLng(lat, lng), {
                    radius: 6,
                    fillColor: color,
                    color: color,        
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    renderer: myRenderer
                }).addTo(layers_variables[value]);

                marker.on('click', onClick_Marker)
                // Attach the corresponding JSON data to your marker:
                marker.id     = id;
                marker.cat_id = value;
                marker.color  = color;
                markerList.push(marker);
                layers_variables_clusters[value].addLayer(marker);
            } //end for loop                                      
        });
    } //end Populate function       
    if(initialise == 0){    
        L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);       
    }  
}
```

Comment: Does this happen when already at max zoom level?

Comment: It was happening when bigger cluster split into smaller and if the points were were close to each other it don't get zoom anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the options bellow to disable the spiderfy and the cluster at higher zoom levels:

**spiderfyOnMaxZoom** and **disableClusteringAtZoom**

There is a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/guihig/eabk5wvj/6/#

Comment: What you explained is true, but id does not answer the question.

Comment: @Ferreira thankyou, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @TomazicM actually i was not able zoom in if the points were close to each other the cluster was splitting on max zoom as shown in the picture, the above  solution solved my problem.